# How to call a task in another object in systemverilog?

Tags: system-verilog

There is a task T under object C, object B and C are in the same level under object A. How could object B call the task T under object C when timeout?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to clarify with some sample code showing the types of A B and C. You also need to define what you meant by a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

- Normal methods cannot be accessed outside its scope.
- However if you have static method defined in, say class C. To access this method in class B, use scope resolution "::" operator with class name.

For e.g. to access static "display" method from class C to class B,

```
class B;

  function void display();
    C::display();
  endfunction

endclass
```